# Проблема с nuget в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Здраствуйте я недавно начал изучением С# установил визуал студио 2012 но каким то образом у меня нугет спрашиваеть обновление как можно решить этот проблему с сайта нугет не смогу установить обновленый нугет Спасибо заране 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему решили начать с 2012 студии? попробуйте поискать в гугле "Ошибка консолидации диспетчера пакетов Visual Studio 2012"

Comment: как можно установит Nlog не исползуя nuget

Comment: У вас де там есть где то список расширений? Там есть нугет? Его можете обновить?

Comment: 1. Переходите на более новую версию VS. 2. По указанной ссылке ходили? 3. Установить nlog, как и любую библиотеку, можно без nuget: идете на сайт библиотеки, скачиваете, добавляете в свой проект.